# Normal distribution, is mean=0 and std_deviation=1?

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling, normalization

Am I correct to say that following the formula

$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi} } e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2}
$

represents a distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$? I tried to verify the case with a short Python code

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm
%matplotlib inline
mu  = 0 # mean
var = 1.0 #variance
sigma = np.sqrt(var) #standard deviation",
x = np.linspace(mu-3*var,mu+3*var, 100)
y = norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma)
plt.plot(x, y);
```

and found `np.mean(y) = 0.1645975096425618` and `n.std(y) = 0.13947206450268224`. I did notice that `y` is non-negative.

Pardon me for my lack of understanding here, but neither does `mean` seem to be 0 nor does `sigma` seem to be 1. Is this how $\mu$ and $\sigma$ calculated suppose to be calculated for $f(x)$? How does one calculate the area under this curve?

[image]

Nonetheless, I was able to make the transformation `z = (y -np.mean(y))/np.std(y)` and found `np.mean(z) = 2.220446049250313e-16` and `n.std(z) = 0.9999999999999999`. So is $z$ the normal distribution with $\mu \approx 0$ and $\sigma \approx 1 $? I am confused.

Update 1:
As per gunes answer, "The formula for the normal distribution PDF is correct. But, np.mean(y) takes the mean of the PDF's y-axis values. From the plot, you can see that these values are all non-negative (as it should be because these are PDF values) and between 0 and 0.4. Same logic applies to deviation."

I wonder if one can literally apply the same logic? The PDF values for `z` has to be negative for some half of its part for the mean to be zero. That's why i was confused else these are not PDF values.

```py
plt.plot(x, z);
```

[image]

Update 2:
I learnt about new updates in `numpy` and tried to sample the new variate(s) as follow

```
s = np.random.default_rng().normal(mu, sigma, 10000)
```

which gives, not to my satisfaction,

```
>>> abs(mu - np.mean(s))
0.0026358298651454506
>>> abs(sigma - np.std(s, ddof=1))
0.004024714057919487
```

I am unhappy and would like to know what's going on when the data is sampled or how is it done? Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Yes that’s the correct expression for a normal density
- You in effect computed $\frac16 \int_{-3}^3 p(x) dx\approx \frac16$ for the mean. You should have computed $\int p(x) x dx$ which you may do numerically by `np.dot(x, y) / y.sum()`
- The quantity `z = (y -np.mean(y))/np.std(y)` has mean 0 and variance 1 by definition. Just try to compute it. But the  fact that it has mean 0 and variance 1 does not mean it is distributed as a standard normal $N(0,1)$.
- You computed the sample mean and sample variance. They are estimates of the mean and variance of the underlying normal distribution that don’t agree exactly with 0 and 1 due to the finite number of samples (`10000`) that you used. Try increasing that number; the differences should decrease.

More generally,

> The PDF values for z has to be negative for some half of its part for the mean to be zero. That's why i was confused else these are not PDF values.

Here and throughout you are confusing the random variable $x$ with the pdf $p(x)$. The PDF is non-negative. The PDF must be non-zero at some negative $x$ in order for the mean of $x$ to be zero.

Comment: Since `z` is obtained from shifting and scaling `f(x)` i.e. `y` which is normal. I would like to say that `z` is a normal distribution too.

Comment: I am wondering where did I set `+/- 6` as the limits?

Comment: Oops that should have said -3,3 and you set them in your np.linespace call

Answer (score 1):

The formula for the normal distribution PDF is correct. But, `np.mean(y)` takes the mean of the PDF's y-axis values. From the plot, you can see that these values are all non-negative (as it should be because these are PDF values) and between 0 and $0.4$. Same logic applies to deviation.

For example: let a RV be either $5$ or $6$ with probabilities $1/2$. If you take the mean of $f(x)$, you'll have $1/2$, but that has nothing to do with the actual mean $5.5$.

For actually calculating the mean of normal random variables, you need to *sample* from $f(x)$. You can use [`numpy.random.normal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html?highlight=numpy%20random%20normal#numpy.random.normal).

Comment: The non-negativity is obvious to me. I didn't put it there to keep the write-up short. Will check out the rest. Thanks.

Comment: I have a question now, instead of using `np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000)`, all I need to do is sample from `f(x)` to get the correct mean and std.deviation, right?

Comment: @Sowmya Yes, you won't calculate the mean & std of f(x). Those are irrelevant. You're going to sample from f(x). Your update 2 is the correct way to sample, and the difference between the sample mean/std and true mean/std is normal. It'll decrease as your sample size increases.

Comment: He doesn’t need to sample: with his setup, np.dot(x, y) / y.sum() should give mean

Comment: @innisfree Yes :) that is the discretised approximation of the theoretical expectation, $\int x f(x) dx$. I suggested sampling because I thought he tries to do so, he wasn't trying to consciously approximate the integral.

Comment: May I know so what does `numpy.random.normal` do in the background?

Comment: It probably uses Box-Müller (or some other method) to create normal RV. Not that trivial for starters.

Comment: It uses Box-Muller: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/464f79eb1d05bf938d16b49da1c39a4e02506fa3/numpy/random/mtrand/randomkit.c#L601